# MediaElement Class Is Not Play the Media file in WPF Application

Tags: wpf

MainWindow.Xaml

```
<MediaElement Margin="10,10,10,0 " Name="McMediaElement" Width="450" Height="250" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Stretch="Fill"
              MediaOpened="Element_MediaOpened" MediaEnded="Element_MediaEnded" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" />
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" Margin="82,0,99,3.52" 
           Name="FileNameLabel" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="LightGreen">
    </Label>
    <Button Height="23" Name="BrowseButton" Width="113" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            Margin="0,0,182,7.04" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            FontWeight="Bold" Click="BrowseButtonClick">
        Browse a Media
    </Button>
```

When Click BrowseButton Its get the file from open Dialog box and it put into the Lable control as FileNameLabel

```
private void BrowseButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog dlg = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
    dlg.Filter = "Media files (*.wmv)|*.wmv|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    dlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string selectedFileName = dlg.FileName;
        FileNameLabel.Content = selectedFileName;
        McMediaElement.Source = new Uri(selectedFileName);
        McMediaElement.UpdateLayout();
        McMediaElement.Play();
    }
}
    private void Element_MediaOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timelineSlider.Maximum = McMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    // When the media playback is finished. Stop() the media to seek to media start.
    private void Element_MediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        McMediaElement.Stop();
    }
```

its does not play the media file.so Plaese Suggest what the problem in code.

Comment: Dumb question, but does the file actually play in Windows Media Player? What happens in `Element_MediaOpened`?

Comment: In This Code We have Problem is that MediaElement is Not Play the .wmv file

Comment: yes, file is its play in Windows Media Player.

Comment: timelineSlider.Maximum = McMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds; this is used in Element_MediaOpened.

Comment: hai Clemens,are oyu see the code that I will be Mention Element_MediaOpened.

Comment: Yes, but it's ok. When opening a media file, do you see any error messages in Visual Studio output window (you have to run in debug mode)?

Comment: Hai clemens,Its Debug then its Give Error::System.Windows.Data Error: 6 : 'TargetDefaultValueConverter' converter failed to convert value 'C:\test\MediaSamples\MediaSamples\Media\Lake.wmv' (type 'String'); fallback value will be used, if available. BindingExpression:Path=Source.LocalPath; DataItem='MediaElement' (Name='McMediaElement'); target element is 'StackPanel' (Name=''); target property is 'Clip' (type 'Geometry') FormatException:'System.FormatException: Unexpected token 'C:\test\MediaSamples\MediaSamples\Media\Lake.wmv' encountered at position '0'.

Comment: That error message should tell you everything you need to fix the error. Obviously a StackPanel's Clip property is bound to the `LocalPath` property of your MediaElement's Source Uri. The converter used in this binding has failed to read the media file.

Comment: Yes Stack Panel Clip Property Is Bound to LocalPath As Like Clip="{Binding ElementName=McMediaElement, Path=Source.LocalPath}" then What will be do for Converter is not failed to read the media file

Comment: What do you intend to do with this binding? To me it doesn't make any sense at all. A file path can obviously not be converted into a Geometry.